# How can I change <s:Envelope to <SOAP-ENV:Envelope if I use wcf?

Tags: .net, wcf, soap

I have a problem with wcf and the soap xml response of my service. How can I change `<s:Envelope` to `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope`? I guess that must be controllable with a property?

I use .NET 4.0, c#, basicHttpBinding and messagecontracts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need this? By XML definition it has absolutely same meaning and I'm affraid it is not possible unless you create your own message encoder.

**Edit:** Here is a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/06/13/changing-prefixes-in-xml-responses.aspx) describing how to replace prefix in custom encoding.

Comment: Hi, 

i know that should be not an problem but in my case the other side, which will receive the response expect this format. maybe i think to complex in this case?!?

br

Comment: This sometimes happens when other side parses messages expecting fixed format.

Comment: You will need customize message encoding. I have added link to article about this topic.

Comment: i'm afraid that this is the only way to solve my problems, i see that blog sometimes during my search, but i hoped i find an another way ... Thanks a lot for informations!

Answer (score 0):

That is only the namespace and should not affect the behavior and functionality of the XML.

What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding, the `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` is the same as  `<s:Envelope xmlns:s=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`. Because the xmlns:soap and xmlns:s has self explanation.